# Function not returning enough object parameters

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that I have modified from some other code, and I am confused. With the 'else if' it seems that the 'Income' object only returns three attributes, rather than the four I need (I can return the value parameter, or I can use the value parameter in a calculation to a different value, but I can't capture both).

```
return {
    addItem: function(type, des, val, price){
        var newItem, ID;
        if(data.allItems[type].length > 0){
            ID = data.allItems[type][data.allItems[type].length - 1].id + 1;
        }else{
            ID = 0; 
        }
        if (type === 'exp'){
            newItem = new Expense(ID, des, val);
        }else if (type === 'inc'){

            var ben = val * price;
            newItem = new Income(ID, des, val, ben);
        }

        data.allItems[type].push(newItem);

        return newItem; 

    },
```

I think my problem lies with this function, but as I say, I am now very confused. Is there an obvious problem with it?

Edit: this is the Income function constructor:

```
var Income = function(id, description, value, price){
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value; 
    this.price = price; 
    this.ben =  ben; 
};
```

Comment: What do you expect to be returned? What actually is returned?

Comment: What do you mean by *the 'Income' object only returns three attributes*?  What does it mean for an object to "return" anything?

Comment: I want the Income objec to return ID, des(cription), val(ue), and ben. It returns ID, description, and either the value, if I leave out the calculation (var ben = val * price), or the calculation if I include it. I need both.

Comment: @Pointy functions are objects...

Comment: Question and code is unclear.Probably the best way to ask a question is to decompose the function into smaller part and write a descriptive paragraph to disclose what that specific part does.People can't just assume and give you feedback

Comment: @AL-zami, thank you, I'll try that, but the code is very long and involved (this in fact was me trying to decompose the function), and I'm very new to Javascript.

Comment: Might be in your in your Constructor itself. Make sure within your `Income()` Constructor you are setting both `val` and `ben` regardless.

Comment: try to give the output you are getting and the output you expect.It would make the post readable.It's not clear what your end goal is!

Comment: Post the code of the `Income` constructor, that's almost certainly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track `ben`, you can add it to the constructor args.

```
var Income = function(id, description, value, price, ben){
```

And add `price` when you instantiate a new `Income` object.

```
newItem = new Income(ID, des, val, price, ben);
```